# Installing SWTBot on Eclipse Indigo RCP

Tags: eclipse-rcp, eclipse-indigo, swtbot

I have eclipse platform version 3.7.1 with eclipse RCP(same version).
I want to install SWTBot feature using "Install New Software". My steps for this:

1. Open "Install New Software" view.
2. Enter in the field update site http://download.eclipse.org/technology/swtbot/releases/latest/
3. Choose only the SWTBot for SWT Testing feature
4. Accept the terms
5. Click "Finish" button
6. Occures the follow problems:

> An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
>       session context was:(profile=epp.package.rcp, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=,
>   action=).
>       Problems downloading artifact: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.swtbot,2.3.0.201506081302.
>       Error reading signed content:C:\Users\Vitos\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile7199240834224524898.jar
>       An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: C:\Users\Vitos\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile7199240834224524898.jar
>       Multiple problems occurred while downloading.
>       Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.swtbot.junit4_x,2.3.0.201506081302.
>       Error reading signed content:C:\Users\Vitos\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile6018721667971083066.jar
>       An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: C:\Users\Vitos\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile6018721667971083066.jar
>       Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.swtbot.junit4_x,2.3.0.201506081302.
>       Error reading signed content:C:\Users\Vitos\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile8872099628154347664.jar
>       An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: C:\Users\Vitos\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile8872099628154347664.jar
>       Multiple problems occurred while downloading.
>       Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.swtbot.swt.finder,2.3.0.201506081302.
>       Error reading signed content:C:\Users\Vitos\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile5589991184774792362.jar
>       An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: C:\Users\Vitos\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile5589991184774792362.jar
>       Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.swtbot.swt.finder,2.3.0.201506081302.
>       Error reading signed content:C:\Users\Vitos\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile5169748035418005227.jar
>       An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: C:\Users\Vitos\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile5169748035418005227.jar

I don't understand, where the problem lies.

Comment: Kindly add some more Content to your Question...

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution of my problem when i inserted the update site org.eclipse.swtbot.updatesite - http://download.eclipse.org/technology/swtbot/releases/2.2.1 instead org.eclipse.swtbot.updatesite - http://download.eclipse.org/technology/swtbot/releases/latest. But, i don't understood what the different?